# In Angular, how to keep on adding component dynamically inside another component on click of a button

Tags: angular

`<app-textbox></app-textbox>` need to be added on every button click.
I know a solution something like-

```
<app-textbox *ngFor="let text in textBoxes"></app-textbox>
```

and on button click, I am pushing some value to textBoxes array.
I am not sure this could be the best solution, I need some best practice related solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to use `text` as a value in your `<app-textbox>` component?

Comment: Yes this is the right way. You can add the textbox components as many time based on the count of the items in the array and pass the value in the child components as required

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with the proposed solution to simply add an entry to the `textBoxes` array. This array in turn will be iterated over and for each entry the `AppTextBoxComponent` will be rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I got some idea with ViewContainerRef and ComponentFactory but not getting any clear idea of how to implement.

Comment: It could look something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-dynamic-component-gen